# Promote docker image in Artifactory using Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, artifactory, promoted-builds

So I'm trying to promote docker image using artifactory jenkins plugin.

```
rtPromote (
buildName: 'MK',
buildNumber: '48',
serverId: 'Artifactory-1',
targetRepo: 'libs-release-local',
sourceRepo: 'libs-snapshot-local',
includeDependencies: true,
failFast: true,
copy: true
```

)

From Jenkins console all seem to be ok and I get the message: "promotion completed successfully"
but in reality nothing happens.
Also, from artifactory logs I'm getting the following:
"Artifactory skipping promotion status update no status received"

Comment: Are you using the correct repo names for promotion? Also, can you confirm if the build MK:48 has all the relevant docker images?

Comment: Are you sure that 'libs-release-local' and 'libs-snapshot-local' are docker repositories?

Comment: I do use the correct repo names and tags, also the repo does exists..  just gave an example

Comment: @shahar did you set MK:48 build in rtDockerPush and rtPublishBuildInfo? Can you provide your rtDockerPush and rtPublishBuildInfo steps?